# How to use react-select with react-hook-form in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-select

I have a form

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(applyFilter)}>
    <FormLabel>Organization</FormLabel>
         <Controller 
          name="Units" 
          control={control} 
          render={({ field }) =>
          <Select 
            {...field} 
             placeholder={translate("Select organization")} 
             options={filterModel.data?.units.map(unit => 
                        { return { label: unit.name, value: unit.id } })} 
             isMulti 
             closeMenuOnSelect={false} 
           />
          }/>
</Form>
```

But i have an error when i try to set options - `type "{ label: string; value: number; }[] | not specified" cannot be specified for the type "OptionsOrGroups<string, GroupBase<string>> | undefined".`

can you help me with this type?

Answer (score 1):

You need the imports like this,

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import Select from 'react-select';
```

Then your hook component can be like this,

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => {})}>
        <div>
          <label>First name</label>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="firstName"
            rules={{ required: true }}
            render={renderProps => {
              const { ref, ...rest } = renderProps.field;

              return (
                <Select
                  options={[{ label: 'Jack', value: '1' }, { label: 'Lisa', value: '2' }]}
                  menuPlacement="auto"              
                  isSearchable={false}
                  menuPortalTarget={document.body} menuPosition="fixed"
                  {...register('firstName')}
                  {...renderProps.field}
                  onChange={e => {
                    console.log(e);
                    renderProps.field.onChange(e);
                  }}
                  
                />
              );
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
```

Comment: I try your solution but have this, when i hover on "value" in options - Type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | GroupBase<string>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'value' does not exist in type 'GroupBase<string>'

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a very general question, but to use react-select with react-hook-form in TypeScript, you need to follow these steps.
Make sure you have the following packages installed in your project:

```
npm install react-select react-hook-form @hookform/resolvers yup
```

Set up the form and form validation

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from 'yup';
```

Define the form schema using yup for validation:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  selectField: yup.string().required('This field is required'),
});
```

Initialize the form and apply the form resolver:

```
const { handleSubmit, control, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
  resolver: yupResolver(schema),
});
```

Add the react-select component

```
import Select from 'react-select';
```

Add the Select component to your form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <Controller
    name="selectField"
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
    render={({ field }) => (
      <Select
        {...field}
        options={options} // Replace with your options array
      />
    )}
  />
  {errors.selectField && <p>{errors.selectField.message}</p>}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```